# Python append performance

Tags: python, performance, append

I'm having some performance problems with 'append' in Python. 
I'm writing an algorithm that checks if there are two overlapping circles in a (large) set of circles.
I start by putting the extreme points of the circles (x_i-R_i & x_i+R_i) in a list and then sorting the list.

```
class Circle:
def __init__(self, middle, radius):
    self.m = middle
    self.r = radius
```

In between I generate N random circles and put them in the 'circles' list.

```
"""
Makes a list with all the extreme points of the circles.
Format = [Extreme, left/right ~ 0/1 extreme, index]
Seperate function for performance reason, python handles local variables faster.
Garbage collect is temporarily disabled since a bug in Python makes list.append run in O(n) time instead of O(1)
"""
def makeList():
    """gc.disable()"""
    list = []
    append = list.append
    for circle in circles:
        append([circle.m[0]-circle.r, 0, circles.index(circle)])
        append([circle.m[0] + circle.r, 1, circles.index(circle)])
    """gc.enable()"""
    return list
```

When running this with 50k circles it takes over 75 seconds to generate the list. As you might see in the comments I wrote I disabled garbage collect, put it in a separate function, used

```
append = list.append
append(foo)
```

instead of just

```
list.append(foo)
```

I disabled gc since after some searching it seems that there's a bug with python causing append to run in O(n) instead of O(c) time.

So is this way the fastest way or is there a way to make this run faster? 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `list` is not a good variable name in python.

Comment: `list` is never a good variable name in any language...

Comment: `"""String literals"""` are not `# comments`.  And docstrings must go inside the function, not before the function.

Comment: @eumiro, CrazyJugglerDrummer: true, changed to cirkeList instead. 
@Sven: Not used to the Python way of commenting things yet, I'll keep your advice in mind.

Answer (score 15):

Instead of

```
for circle in circles:
    ... circles.index(circle) ...
```

use

```
for i, circle in enumerate(circles):
    ... i ...
```

This could decrease your O(n^2) to O(n).

Your whole `makeList` could be written as:

```
sum([[[circle.m[0]-circle.r, 0, i], [circle.m[0]+circle.r, 1, i]] for i, circle in enumerate(circles)], [])
```

Comment: @Harm this is good advice - you should also consider using a deque for this (see collections module) as it has reportedly marginally better performance for append operations. You may then want to convert it to a list at the end though, so the savings might not outweigh the overhead.

Comment: Ah ok, I was looking at the wrong thing the whole time.. Thanks for the answer :)
Care to explain why getting the index of a circle is O(N²)? O(n) I would understand since getting the index of an object in a list equals linearly searching trough the list until you find that object.

Comment: @Harm: The linear search is done in each of the n iterations of the for-loop, giving a total of O(n*n).

Comment: @Harm: one single `.index()` is O(n), but doing it for every element of the list makes it O(n^2).

Comment: @Sven,eumiro: goddamnit, I'm really paying attention am I? Tsss.

One last question, what exactly does a mathematical operator like sum do while making the list? Could you explain what happens in that line of code?

Comment: He's misusing `sum` to concatenate lots of lists - `sum([x, y, z] default)` is `default + x + y + z`. Has quite suboptimal performance by the way - it first creates a large list in memory, then makes n time `O(n)` concatenation with them. A better one-liner would be `list(item for i, circle in enumerate(circles) for item in ([circle.m[0]-circle.r, 0, i], [circle.m[0]+circle.r, 1, i])` which avoids having all data in memory before construction the list and builds the whole result list at once without concats.

Answer (score 7):

Your performance problem is not in the `append()` method, but in your use of `circles.index()`, which makes the whole thing O(n^2).

A further (comparitively minor) improvement is to use a list comprehension instead of `list.append()`:

```
mylist = [[circle.m[0] - circle.r, 0, i]
          for i, circle in enumerate(circles)]
mylist += [[circle.m[0] + circle.r, 1, i]
           for i, circle in enumerate(circles)]
```

Note that this will give the data in a different order (which should not matter as you are planning to sort it anyway).

Comment: I'm quite new to Python and am still learning about python-esque things like list comprehensions. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 5):

**I've just tried several tests to improve "append" function's speed. It will definitely helpful for you.**

1. Using Python
2. Using list(map(lambda  -  known as a bit faster means than for+append
3. Using Cython
4. Using Numba - jit

## CODE CONTENT : getting numbers from 0 ~ 9999999, square them, and put them into a new list using append.

1. Using Python

   ```
   import timeit

   st1 = timeit.default_timer()

   def f1():

       a = range(0, 10000000)

       result = []
       append = result.append

       for i in a:
           append( i**2 )

       return result

   f1()


   st2 = timeit.default_timer()
   print("RUN TIME : {0}".format(st2-st1))
   ```

> RUN TIME : 3.7 s

2. Using list(map(lambda

   ```
   import timeit

   st1 = timeit.default_timer()

   result = list(map(lambda x : x**2 ,  range(0,10000000) ))

   st2 = timeit.default_timer()
   print("RUN TIME : {0}".format(st2-st1))
   ```

> RUN TIME : 3.6 s

3. Using Cython

   - the coding in a .pyx file

     def f1():
         cpdef double i
         a = range(0, 10000000)

     ```
     result = []
     append = result.append

     for i in a:
         append( i**2 )

     return result
     ```

and I compiled it and ran it in .py file.

- in .py file

  ```
  import timeit
  from c1 import *

  st1 = timeit.default_timer()

  f1()

  st2 = timeit.default_timer()
  print("RUN TIME : {0}".format(st2-st1))
  ```

> RUN TIME : 1.6 s

4. Using Numba - jit

   ```
   import timeit
   from numba import jit

   st1 = timeit.default_timer()

   @jit(nopython=True, cache=True)
   def f1():

       a = range(0, 10000000)

       result = []
       append = result.append

       for i in a:
           append( i**2 )

       return result

   f1()

   st2 = timeit.default_timer()
   print("RUN TIME : {0}".format(st2-st1))
   ```

> RUN TIME : 0.57 s

## CONCLUSION :

As you mentioned above, changing the simple append form boosted up the speed a bit. And using Cython is much faster than in Python. However, turned out using Numba is the best choice in terms of speed improvement for 'for+append' !

Answer (score 2):

Try using [deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) in the collections package to append large rows of data, without performance diminishing. And then convert a deque back to a DataFrame using [List Comprehension](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-list-comprehension).

Sample Case:

```
from collections import deque

d = deque()
for row in rows:
 d.append([value_x, value_y])

df = pd.DataFrame({'column_x':[item[0] for item in d],'column_y':[item[1] for item in d]})
```

This is a real time-saver.

Answer (score 1):

If performance were an issue, I would avoid using append. Instead, preallocate an array and then fill it up. I would also avoid using index to find position within the list "circles". Here's a rewrite. It's not compact, but I'll bet it's fast because of the unrolled loop.

```
def makeList():
    """gc.disable()"""
    mylist = 6*len(circles)*[None]
    for i in range(len(circles)):
        j = 6*i
        mylist[j] = circles[i].m[0]-circles[i].r
        mylist[j+1] = 0
        mylist[j+2] = i
        mylist[j+3] = circles[i].m[0] + circles[i].r
        mylist[j+4] = 1
        mylist[j+5] = i
    return mylist
```